# Importing ng2-bootstrap modal in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to use modal of [**ng2-bootstrap**](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap). So I configured everything equals to the examples as below:

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
        ModalModule
    ],
    providers: [ ]
})
```

However I'm still getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

**Component:**

```
import { ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'any-comp',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './any-comp.component.html'
})
export class AnyCompComponent implements OnInit {

private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(
    private pageContentService: PageContentService,
    viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="lgModal.show()">Large modal</button>

<div bsModal="bsmodal" #lgmodal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Large modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template variables are case sensitive, in your case it is `#lgmodal` (lowercase "m") and you are trying to show `lgModal` on click (uppercase "M"): `(click)="lgModal.show()"`. So, just change your template variable so it matches the one from `(click)` event: `#lgModal`.

Comment: Of course, that's correct! A silly mistake when converting html to pug. Thanks :)